# Image Caroussel without PageView

Tags: flutter, dart

I know there are already a couple of similar questions, but they don't help me.
I'm trying to make a Pictures horizontally scrollable, but when I do it with PageView the whole Page gets filled with it and I can't see other content. 
I have some Text and below I want my Image Caroussel to appear and below it, I want some Text again. 
I achieved it almost with a Listview and the scroll direction to horizontally, but you only should be able to scroll Image by Image.
Is there a possibility to make a PageView with viewportFraction: 1.0 without filling out everything?

Edit: The problem is, that my other content is in a Stack with a fit of Stackfit.expand.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package for this: [Flutter Swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

Comment: I will definitely give it a try. Thank you